# How to integrate ID info into binomial GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model

I have data from an experiment where we tagged and released lobsters (*n* = 31) at an aquaculture site and followed them over a 2 months period.

The question is simple: do lobsters stay longer IN the aquaculture site or OUT (or there’s no difference)?

We determined the time (variable "Time.min") each lobster (variable "ID") was located (variable "Loc") "In" and "Out" the aquaculture site, determined the total time the position of each lobster was recorded by acoustic telemetry (TotalT.min), and determine the proportion of time each lobster stayed "In" and "Out" the aquaculture site (variable "Time.prop").

Here’s a subset of my data:

```
ID      Sex    Size Loc Time.min    TotalT.min  Time.prop
33199       F   63  In  493          914        0.5394
33199       F   63  Out 421          914        0.4606
33205       M   68  In  0            784        0
33205       M   68  Out 784          784        1
33206       M   69  In  0            155        0
33206       M   69  Out 155          155        1
33207       F   62  In  0            230        0
33207       F   62  Out 230          230        1
33208       M   66  In  3969        6773        0.5860
33208       M   66  Out 2804        6773        0.4140
33210       F   63  In  88           351        0.2515
33210       F   63  Out 263          351        0.7485
33211       F   58  In  99           376        0.2630
33211       F   58  Out 277          376        0.7370
33212       M   84  In  63           395        0.1593
33212       M   84  Out 332          395        0.8407
33213       M   63  In  183          1029       0.1778
33213       M   63  Out 846          1029       0.8222
33214       M   73  In  1522        2096        0.7263
33214       M   73  Out 574         2096        0.2736
```

You’ll notice there are 2 observations for each individual (i.e. 1 observation “In” aquaculture site and 1 observation “Out”)

I created this model which seems to give sensible results:

```
glm.time <- glm(Time.prop ~ Loc + Sex + Size + Loc:Sex + Loc:Size + Sex:Size,
              weights = TotalT.min, family = quasibinomial, data = mydata)
summary(glm.time)

Call:
glm(formula = Time.prop ~ Loc + Sex + Size + Loc:Sex + Loc:Size + 
Sex:Size, family = quasibinomial, data = mydata, weights = TotalT.min)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-126.19   -25.14     0.00    25.14   126.19  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  9.270e+00  1.120e+01   0.828  0.41137   
LocOut      -1.854e+01  9.564e+00  -1.939  0.05769 . 
SexM         1.885e+00  1.167e+01   0.161  0.87231   
Size        -1.534e-01  1.868e-01  -0.821  0.41512   
LocOut:SexM -3.769e+00  1.223e+00  -3.082  0.00321 **
LocOut:Size  3.067e-01  1.591e-01   1.928  0.05905 . 
SexM:Size    1.561e-15  1.915e-01   0.000  1.00000   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 2469.838)

    Null deviance: 222187  on 61  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 142158  on 55  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

However, I don’t know if I should or how to integrate the information about the individuals into my model. It looks to me that I should tell the model that there are 31 individuals with the proportion of time “In” and the proportion of time “Out”. Right now, it looks more like there are 62 individuals, and 31 spend some time “In and 31 spend some time “Out”.

Is my model is adequate? If not, do you know how to integrate the ID to my model?

Comment: How do you know the sex of the lobster?

Comment: Lobster were collected using cages, measured, sex was determined visually (males and females are slightly different), an acoustic tag was glued on each lobster, and they were released.

Comment: The problem could be due to the uncertain classification of the lobster's sex.

Comment: Thank you for your interest @Michael. I didn't determined the sex of the lobsters myself but I know this is very easy to do. Our people on the field know what to look for and get the right sex 100% of the time so there's no uncertainty there. My question is more about the way I analyze the data then the data itself. Is it ok to have 2 observations for each lobster (the way I did it) or should I somehow include the information about each lobster (variable "ID") in the model (e.g. using a mixed model)?

Comment: Two observations per lobster is not okay.

Comment: Ok thank you for your input @Michael. Do you have a suggestion to fix this? I tried to rework my data set using "time.in" and "time.out" variables. This way I have 1 observation per lobster with the proportion of time in and out the aquaculture site. Using `cbind` I ran this model: `glm.time.cbind <- glm(cbind(Time.in,Time.out)~Sex*Size, data = mydata2, family=quasibinomial)`. However, my results only tell me if the if Sex and/or Size affect the time.in/time.out but I don't know if they actually spend more time in or out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset is redundant. Whenever a lobster's not in, it's out, so the second row of your dataset provides no information not also provided by the first, and so on for all even rows and the row just above each them. Redundancy of this sort is a particularly extreme violation of the assumption of independent sampling.  Once you remove the even rows, you have only one observation per lobster, so there's no need to consider lobster ID.

Comment: Thanks @Kodiologist. I agree with your concern (that's why I posted my question here) however by doing this I can't test whether they spend more time in or out. If you look at my original question I loose my "Loc" variable which is the most important. How to fix this?

Comment: "by doing this I can't test whether they spend more time in or out" — Sure you can. That's determined by the intercept. (Or if you didn't want to control for all those other variables, don't bother with regression.)

Comment: yes I'll know if they spend more time in or out. However, how to know if that's significant or not? From my understanding, a significant intercept means that the intercept is significantly different from zero, not necessarily that the 2 groups (time in, time out) are significantly different, is that right?

Comment: @MudWarrior You're using logistic regression, right? So the intercept is 0 if and only if (with dummy variables at their reference levels and categorical predictors at 0) the lobsters spend an equal amount of time in and out. If it's positive, they spend more time in whichever state you coded as 1; if it's negative, they spend more time in whichever state you coded as 0. So a significance test of the intercept is what you want, it seems.

Comment: Well done, thanks for your help and clear explanations! I knew I was doing something wrong but I didn't know how to build my test right. The significance test on the intercept is what I needed.

Comment: Do you know any sources (e.g. stats book, published literature) that suggested or used the significance test on the intercept on a similar way as I do? I can already hear the reviewer's comment on this!

Comment: @MudWarrior Not off the top of my head. If the reviewer complains, it shouldn't be difficult to take him or her through the mathematics. If you're weak on logistic regression, now's a good time to brush up.

Comment: @MudWarrior If you want more direct help, I'm happy to coauthor your paper. ;)